# Where can I get Microsoft Windows peer-to-peer networking speed characteristics?

Tags: windows, networking, speed, peer-to-peer

Where can I get Microsoft Windows peer-to-peer networking speed characteristics? 
I need to know if and what speed advantages you get with it over `net.tcp` and other ws-* bindings and if it is faster than Flash 10.1 p2p and classic [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) P2P?

Is it good for live video broadcasting?

Is there any research in this field?

Comment: You need to ask on SuperUser.com

Comment: You should go through your questions on Super User and accept some of the answers.

Comment: And please edit out the CAPITAL LETTERS in the title.